# how to code behind a html button?

Tags: c#, html, button, code-behind

I am trying to redirect to Search.aspx after login button is clicked. the login button is a html5 button. I googled and they say to make it work is to add the runat="server" and önserverclick="Button1_Click". After I done that, I double click on the login button on design mode. and it generates

```
function Button1_onclick() {

            }
```

I put the Response.Redirect("Search.aspx"); inside the function. And it still have no effect when I click the Login button.

[image]

**SOURCE CODE**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/loginstyle.css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[




        function Button1_onclick() {
            Response.Redirect("Search.aspx");
        }

// ]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="" method="post">

        <div class="header">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <span>Fill out the form below to login to my super awesome imaginary control panel.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
        <input name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="Username" />
        <div class="user-icon"></div>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Password" />
        <div class="pass-icon"></div>       
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" runat="server" id="Button1" önserverclick="Button1_Click"  onclick="return Button1_onclick()" />
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
<div class="gradient"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

CODE BEHIND CODE(NOCODE)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: How does this relate to HTML5 ? Code behind is ASP.NET server-side codes. Also, your DOCTYPE is XHTML 1.0, not HTML5

Comment: erm maybe I should changed it to, how to code behind a html button? @Raptor

Comment: `önserverclick` ? `ö` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code I hope it would help!!

```
function Button1_onclick() 
  {
  window.location.assign("Search.aspx")
  }
```

Comment: Erm thanks it worked. But I am gonna code the login button. After typing correct username and password. Click the login button and it will redirect to Search.aspx. Will I meet any problems? Is it only for redirecting, then i only need that window.location.assign code?  @Neel

Comment: you can use if else condition like whenever the user has entered correct requirement then redirect to this page else redirect to another page! @Jordjmax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603037/cant-work-using-html-textbox-to-login  I created another thread about my problem about logging in using hardcode. Help me when u r free? thanks @Neel

Comment: must I type my code in the source code? Is there no way to generate a code behind in aspx.cs file? It's like harder to code in the source code. Now I want to add session to my login code, and it can;t work @Neel

Comment: you can create session in javascript like this :- Session["controlID"] ="This is my session"; @Jordjmax

Comment: and you can use ajax call to transfer your data to your code behind file @Jordjmax