# Can';t work using html textbox to login

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, authentication, code-behind

Because I am using html buttons and textbox to login, I must do the code behind in the javascript in the source code in order to do the code behind. Whether I login using the correct username and password which is Admin and 123 and click the login button, or I type in nothing and click the login button, it always redirects me to ResultDetails.aspx. That means login fail. Login will pass if it redirect me to Search.aspx. What's Wrong? Even if I change .Value to .Text, it is still the same effect

[image]

**MY SOURCE CODE**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/loginstyle.css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[




        function Button1_onclick() {

            if (txtUserName.Value == "Admin" && txtPassword.Value == "123") {
                //Login as Hardcoded User

                //Do your stuff
                window.location.assign("Search.aspx")


            }
            else {
                window.location.assign("ResultDetails.aspx")
            }           
        }

// ]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="" method="post">

        <div class="header">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>
        <span>Fill out the form below to login to my super awesome imaginary control panel.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
        <input name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="Username" runat="server" id="txtUserName" />
        <div class="user-icon"></div>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Password" runat="server" id="txtPassword" />
        <div class="pass-icon"></div>       
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" runat="server" id="Button1" önserverclick="Button1_Click"  onclick="return Button1_onclick()" />
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
<div class="gradient"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**MY CODE BEHIND CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code which fetches the value from text boxes using the id in JavaScript.

```
function Button1_onclick() {

            if (document.getElementById('txtUserName').value == "Admin" && document.getElementById('txtPassword').value == "123") {
                //Login as Hardcoded User

                //Do your stuff
                window.location.assign("Search.aspx")


            }
            else {
                window.location.assign("ResultDetails.aspx")
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You are **not using asp.net server controls** to access values like

```
txtUserName.Value
```

Rather, you are using `Javascript on HTML` Controls. So, your syntax should be like:

```
if (document.getElementById("txtUserName").value == "Admin" && document.getElementById("txtPassword").value == "123")
```

Comment: must I type my code in the source code? Is there no way to generate a code behind in aspx.cs file? It's like harder to code in the source code. Now I want to add session to my login code, and it can;t work @Avinash Kothamasu

Comment: You are doing login in the client side. Sessions are on the server side. It is always preferred to do server side login functionality rather than client side hardcording. your security is nothing, when javascript for your site is diasbled, any anonymous user can log into the system.

Answer (score 4):

You need to access the fields properly

e.g.

```
if (document.getElementById('txtUserName').value == "Admin" && document.getElementById('txtPassword').value == "123")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Jquery lib in your code
You can also do

```
if($.("#txtUserName").val()=="Admin" && $.("#txtPasword").val()=="123")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (document.getElementById("txtUserName").value == "Admin" 
    && document.getElementById("txtPassword").value == "123")
```